# Laravel beforeFilter in controller on POST request throws non-object exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I try to set some specific filter on all controller methods with:

```
public function __construct() {

   $this->beforeFilter(function(){
     //whathever
   });
}
```

and it's working well on normal GET methods, problem occures when there is some POST method:

```
Route::post('settings/menu-order/{direction}', array(
                                            'as' => 'setting.menu-order.move',
                                            'uses' => function($direction) {
        $controller = new CMSSettingsController();
        return $controller->doMoveMenu($direction);
}));
```

after click in a button which send POST with $direction, I'v got

```
Call to a member function filter() on a non-object
```

in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php

```
protected function registerClosureFilter(Closure $filter)
{
    $this->getFilterer()->filter($name = spl_object_hash($filter), $filter);
    return $name;
}
```

If I use already registred filter it's working, so what's going on?
I have few controllers which need specific function todo before running controller methods, so I can't make global universal filter. Is there any other good solution?

Comment: Why don't you specify the [filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) in your `routes.php`?

Comment: It's becouse almost each controller would have it's own filter and i thought it can be messy to write all of them there. It is some solution but i would like to know why unnamed filters doesn't work, I already tried to find something about such errors, but i found only same Q without any answer (http://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2014-controller-closure-or-method-beforefilters-throwing-exceptions)

Comment: You can create [route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups) for routes that share a common filter. You can even have groups inside your groups. For example, you could have a group for each controller you have (with the controller filter) and any other route inside that group will inherit that filter.

Comment: You have right, but I already know it. Still I have to write all of those filters and store them, and I would preffer to not fill any file with one-time-used methods. Anyway @Ben, thanks for responses (if I wouldn't make it working I will use groups in groups i guess, already have one group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that you are calling the controller action directly instead of letting the Router do it for you.  When the router tries to apply the filters, instead of applying them on the controller, it ends up attempting to apply them on the **output** of the `doMoveMenu` action - which, of course, is not a `Controller` object and has no method `filter`.

Instead, your route should look like this:

```
Route::post('settings/menu-order/{direction}', array(
                'as' => 'setting.menu-order.move',
                'uses' => 'CMSSettingsController@doMoveMenu'));
```

The reason you don't need to do the method call manually is that since your Route has a parameter in it and your method accepts a parameter, the Router will automatically pass the parameter into the action method.  Additionally, since you are providing a method name as the `uses` value, Laravel knows that it has to instantiate the Controller and run the filters.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer, it is working right now. I understand it now why it wasn't working. It's Your solution so maybe You can write it on link that I have post before, there is no any answer still there.